# Every family $\mathscr{A} $ of sets satisfies $|\mathscr{A} \setminus \mathscr{A}| \geq |\mathscr{A}|$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

Let $\mathscr{A} $ be a set of sets. Let's denote $\{A 
\setminus B : A,B \in \mathscr{A}\}$ by $\mathscr{A} \setminus \mathscr{A} $.

The *Marica-Schönheim* theorem in combinatorics says that $|\mathscr{A} \setminus \mathscr{A}| \geq |\mathscr{A}|$ for every finite $\mathscr{A}$.

This immediately implies the result for countably-infinite $\mathscr{A}$, since if we had $|\mathscr{A} \setminus \mathscr{A}|=n $ is finite, then taking a subset of size $n+1$ out of $\mathscr{A}$ gives a contradiction.

There seems to be no natural one-to-one mapping $\mathscr{A} \to \mathscr{A} \setminus \mathscr{A} $, so this raises the question:

> Do we have $|\mathscr{A} \setminus \mathscr{A}| \geq |\mathscr{A}|$ for families $\mathscr{A}$ of arbitrary cardinality?

Comment: Do your perhaps mean $\{ A \setminus B : A,B \in \mathscr{A} \}$? The set you wrote down has one element...

Comment: I do, thank you. Edited accordingly.

Comment: If the inequality holds then equality holds, because for infinite $\mathscr{A}$ you have
$$|\mathscr{A} \setminus \mathscr{A}| \leq|\mathscr{A} \times \mathscr{A}| = |\mathscr{A}|,$$
assuming the axiom of choice.

Comment: @Servaes Yes, I noticed this too. Thanks.

Comment: For every set, $X$, $X\setminus X$ is empty.

Comment: @Asaf Yes, of course. Perhaps you are dissatisfied with this overriding of the usual meaning of \setminus?

Comment: Yes, I am. Some symbols shouldn't be overloaded.

Comment: Well, this is how Noga Alon denotes it in his monumental book "The Probabilistic Method". Ron Holzman&Aharoni use the symbol ~ in their paper, which may be less suggestive.

Comment: @Leullame: Shame, then.

Comment: @Leullame Where do Alon and Spencer do that in the book?

Comment: @Did It is corollary 6.1.4 in the 4th edition . It appears in chapter 6 in the older editions too.

Comment: @Leullame This seems to be the unique and only occurrence in the whole book (which does not make it a good notational choice, eventhough the authors define it carefully).